# Array List compare with the String but the duplicate record is inserting in the sqlite

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, android-service, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert the record in the sqlite table for that I am doing these step.

Step 1--> I am getting the value from the Sqlite table and storing that in the Arraylist.

Step 2-->Now fetch the record from the Url

Step 3--> Now I am comparing the id which i fetch the URL and the Arraylist which i get from the Sqlite. if the record is not present then i call the insert query.

Problem--> Its work fine when i get the single record but when my array list has three different record then it insert the record three times.

This is i am doing to fill the array list from the Sqlite table

```
      localstoragehandler = new LocalStorageHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    dbCursor=localstoragehandler.view_group("1");
                    if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0){
                        int noOfScorer = 0;
                        dbCursor.moveToFirst();
                        while ((!dbCursor.isAfterLast())&&noOfScorer<dbCursor.getCount())
                        {
                            noOfScorer++;
                            String id_sql = dbCursor.getString(0);
                            String grp_id = dbCursor.getString(1);
                            String grp_name = dbCursor.getString(2);
                            String grp_created_by = dbCursor.getString(3);
                            String grp_status = dbCursor.getString(4);
                            String grp_date=dbCursor.getString(5);
                            String grp_member=dbCursor.getString(6);
                            String grp_img=dbCursor.getString(7);
                            if (!compare_grp_list.contains(grp_id)) {

                                compare_grp_list.add(grp_id);
                                Log.e("grp_inside",grp_id+"---->add");

                            }
                            dbCursor.moveToNext();
                        }

                        Log.e("count grp", String.valueOf(dbCursor.getCount())+"---->count");


                    }
                    if (!compare_grp_list.contains("0")) {
                        compare_grp_list.add("0");
                    }

                    Log.e("Array list", String.valueOf(compare_grp_list));
                    abc_grp = socketOperator.grpHttpUpdate(finall_id);
                    FillGroup(abc_grp);
```

Now the code below i am using for parse the data i fetch from the url and when i get the success i am trying to insert the record into the Sqlite table.

```
public void FillGroup(String Content){


    Log.e("wait", "come");
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    String result="";
    String grp_id="";
    String grp_name="";
    String grp_created_by="";
    String grp_status="";
    String grp_date="";
    String grp_member="";
    String grp_img="";
    String result_grp="";

    /////////user///////

    String id="";
    String user_name="";
    String user_phone="";
    String user_email="";
    String user_image="";
    String flag1="";
    String flag2="";

    int lengthJsonArr=0;

    try {
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);
  //            Log.e("jsonResponseGrp", String.valueOf(jsonResponse));
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

         lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();
  //            Log.e("lengthJsonArr", String.valueOf(lengthJsonArr)+"");
        for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
        {

            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            grp_id = jsonChildNode.optString("grp_id").toString();
            grp_name=jsonChildNode.optString("grp_name").toString();
            grp_created_by= jsonChildNode.optString("grp_created_by").toString();
            grp_status     = jsonChildNode.optString("grp_status").toString();
            grp_date = jsonChildNode.optString("grp_date").toString();
            grp_member = jsonChildNode.optString("grp_member").toString();
            grp_img = jsonChildNode.optString("grp_member").toString();
            result_grp = jsonChildNode.optString("result").toString();
            Log.e("grp_id",grp_id);
            Log.e("grp_name",grp_name);
            Log.e("grp_created_by",grp_created_by);
            Log.e("grp_status",grp_status);
            Log.e("grp_date",grp_date);
            Log.e("grp_member",grp_member);
            Log.e("grp_img", grp_img);
            //TODO INSERT GROUP


            /////////////////////User//////////////////////

            id = jsonChildNode.optString("id").toString();
            user_name = jsonChildNode.optString("user_name").toString();
            user_phone = jsonChildNode.optString("user_phone").toString();
            user_email = jsonChildNode.optString("user_email").toString();
            user_image = jsonChildNode.optString("user_image").toString();
            flag1 = jsonChildNode.optString("flag1").toString();
            flag2 = jsonChildNode.optString("flag2").toString();


  //                localstoragehandler.insert_user(id,user_name,user_phone,user_email,user_image,flag1,flag2);


    //                Log.e("Data of Group",id+" - "+user_name+user_phone+user_email+user_image+flag1+flag2 );
        }
        if (result_grp.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){

            for(int j=0;j<compare_grp_list.size();j++){
                Log.e("compare check",compare_grp_list.get(j)+"array");
                if (!compare_grp_list.contains(grp_id)){
                    Log.e("my checking",grp_id+"checking--->395");
                    Log.e("my compare checkin", compare_grp_list + "checking--->396");
                    localstoragehandler.insert_group(grp_id, grp_name, grp_created_by, grp_status, grp_date, grp_member, grp_img);
                    showNotificationGroup(grp_name);

                }


            }

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

This all i am doing inside the service class.

Thanks in advance. please help me.

Comment: check if you have added the insert code in the loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply @VivekMishra. you want to say that i have to remove the code inside the for loop. means that line localstoragehandler.insert_group(grp_id, grp_name, grp_created_by, grp_status, grp_date, grp_member, grp_img);

Comment: I would suggest after comparing add them to list or array as you like and then insert that array or list into database in one go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have used **contains** so that some string partially matched. so that it added repeatedly

**equals( )** or **equalsIgnoreCase( )**  method

instead of

```
  if (!compare_grp_list.contains(grp_id)){
    }
```

Reference

```
     String a = "ABCdefGHIjkl";
     String b = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
     String c = "ABCd";
     String d = "abcd";

     if(a.contains(c))==true    
     if(a.equals(c))== false
     if(d.equalsIgnoreCase(c))==true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sasikumar but when i try this it repeatedly added the value in the arraylist.  E/Array list: [5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 0, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0]

Comment: before that check database table insert query wheather is in loop or not? and also set primary key in db column

Comment: to set the column as primary key is work for me Thanks a lot @sasikumar but now i am facing one new issue can you plz help me in that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715559/how-to-set-a-column-as-autoincrement-without-making-it-as-primary-key-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

You have to override equals method for comparable class to check instance equality.

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof YourClass )) return false;

        YourClass that = (YourClass) obj;

        if (this.grp_name == null) return (that.grp_name == null);
        if (this.grp_phone == null) return (that.grp_phone == null);
        ....
        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() { // Always override hashCode AND equals
        return str.toLowerCase().hashCode();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion nut make the column as an primary key is work for me..one upvote for your help...can you plz help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715559/how-to-set-a-column-as-autoincrement-without-making-it-as-primary-key-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

You've got some nasty error in logic.

lengthJsonArr can be > 0 . But you store only last value in local fields

```
String result="";
    String grp_id="";
    String grp_name="";
    String grp_created_by="";
    String grp_status="";
    String grp_date="";
    String grp_member="";
    String grp_img="";
    String result_grp="";

    /////////user///////

    String id="";
    String user_name="";
    String user_phone="";
    String user_email="";
    String user_image="";
    String flag1="";
    String flag2="";
```

So because of that you check only last result `(result_grp.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){` and add the last value `compare_grp_list.size()` times to DataBase.

Try to move the  braces to the end of loop//                Log.e("Data of Group",id+" - "+user_name+user_phone+user_email+user_image+flag1+flag2 );
        }
        if (result_grp.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){

Comment: thanks @aelimill but this is my json format where i get the Success as a static variable for comparing.
http://pastie.org/10682937

Comment: thanks for your suggestion nut make the column as an primary key is work for me..one upvote for your help